# Using a variable as a classname

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, url

I am trying to put a class name stored in a variable into my JQuery where I want the class to be, this should change which class is affected depending on the parameter passed through the URL query string. 
I have built the class name and stored it in the 'param' variable as below.

```
var param = '".' + "proj" + location.search.substring(6) + '"';
      $(param).css('display', 'inline');
```

And want to change the css on the class inside of it but this does not seem to work for me. Perhaps because it tries to change the css of the variable rather than what is inside of it. 
If not how can I solve this or if so, is there a better way I could go about this?

Comment: Remove the `"` quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing a string literal to be only enclosed by double quotes `"`, while that is not the case. Remove them

```
var param = '.' + "proj" + location.search.substring(6);
```

Comment: Oh I see, if you called a class name directly you would put them in double quotes i.e. $("proj4").css('display', 'inline'); 
So that must be why I was mistaken. Thanks Amit.

Answer (score 0):

Set the param variable as the location substring (assuming that this substring is correctly getting the desired result from your URL)  - then use that in the jQuery by joining with the common portion as follows.

```
var param = location.search.substring(6);
$('.proj' + param).css('display', 'inline');
```

You will need to ensure that a) you have the jQuery library and b) you have the jquery code wrapped in a $(document).ready(function(){}) wrapper.

Also - its usually better to add / remove a class rather than directly affecting the CSS in the jquery

```
var param = location.search.substring(6);
$('.proj' + param).addClass('displayInline');

//CSS
.displayInline{display: inline}
```